# Get text surrounding the matched element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In the following HTML...

```
<p>abc<span class='blue'>def</span>ghi</p>
```

...I want to get the character of text immediately preceding the `span` element (in this case the letter *c*). Assume that the string between the `p` tags is of arbitrary contents and length, and that the `span` element could be anywhere in between the `p` tags. When the opening `p` tag is adjacent to the opening `span` tag, an empty string should be returned.

Is there a convenient way to retrieve such with jQuery?

Comment: I think something along the lines of `$(".blue").parent().html();` and some regex might be your best bet. I don't know of a better way, other than wrapping the stuff youre interested in inside it's own class - which is not handy for dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var prevLetters = $('span.blue')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue,
    lastLetter = prevLetters.substring(prevLetters.length - 1);
```

```js
var prevLetters = $('span.blue')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue;

var lastLetter = prevLetters.substring(prevLetters.length - 1);
console.log(lastLetter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc<span class='blue'>def</span>ghi</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5tjue/1/).

This finds all the elements matching the selector and then, using the `[0]` notation, switches to the DOM node (rather than the jQuery object), and selects the previous sibling (a `textNode`) and finds its `nodeValue`.

This is then modified using the `substring()` to give only the last letter.

---

**Edited**: to meet the requirement of an empty string, if the `span` tag is the first child of the parent:

```
var prevLetters, lastLetter;
if ($('span.blue')[0].previousSibling) {
    prevLetters = $('span.blue')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue;
    lastLetter = prevLetters.substring(prevLetters.length - 1);
}
else {
    lastLetter = '';
}
```

```js
var prevLetters, lastLetter;
if ($('span.blue')[0].previousSibling) {
  prevLetters = $('span.blue')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue;
  lastLetter = prevLetters.substring(prevLetters.length - 1);
} else {
  lastLetter = '';
}
console.log(lastLetter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class='blue'>def</span>ghi</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5tjue/2/).

---

**Edited** and turned into a function:

```
function prevLetter(elem){
    if (!elem){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var prevLetters, lastLetter;
        if (elem.previousSibling){
            prevLetters = elem
                .previousSibling
                .nodeValue;
            lastLetter = prevLetters
                .substring(prevLetters.length-1);
        }
        else {
            lastLetter = '';
        }
    }
    return lastLetter;
}

var lastLetter = prevLetter($('span.blue')[0]);
```

```js
function prevLetter(elem) {
  if (!elem) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var prevLetters, lastLetter;
    if (elem.previousSibling) {
      prevLetters = elem
        .previousSibling
        .nodeValue;
      lastLetter = prevLetters
        .substring(prevLetters.length - 1);
    } else {
      lastLetter = '';
    }
  }
  return lastLetter;
}

var lastLetter = prevLetter($('span.blue')[0]);
console.log(lastLetter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc<span class='blue'>def</span>ghi</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5tjue/3/).

And, finally, a pure JavaScript answer which changes the selector from a jQuery selector, utilising `document.querySelectorAll()` where available, to a DOM selector utilising `document.querySelectorAll()` directly (all other code remains the same as in the function above):

```
var lastLetter = prevLetter(document.querySelectorAll('span.blue')[0]);
console.log(lastLetter);

// or:
var lastLetter = prevLetter(document.querySelector('span.blue'));
console.log(lastLetter);
```

The key difference between the last two is that `querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of elements, whether that collection has none, one or many elements - and therefore requires the use of an index to retrieve a particular element, whereas `querySelector()` returns only one – the first – matching Node, or `null` if no matching nodes were found.

References:

- [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/Node.nodeValue).
- [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/Node.previousSibling).
- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: celver :) aside from the selector, is this pure JS?

Comment: Only issue is the part about "When the opening p tag is adjacent to the opening span tag, an empty string should be returned."  This will blow up.  Easily overcome of course, just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @jammypeach: yes `$('span.blue')[0]` gets the original DOM object

Comment: @JamesMontagne: yeah, I didn't catch that until I saw your comment, thanks! And edited/amended to deal with that. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the expected solution demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/EyYLx/):

Code as below:

```
var all=$("p").text(); // everything inside <p>
var sub=$("span ").text(); // everything inside <span>
var pos= all.indexOf(sub)-1; // place of just letter before span
alert(all[pos]);​
```